# send array to function in php

Tags: php, function, arrays

Here is the code :

```
function dosomething ()
{
  ... do something with the array... like print value !
}

$ar = array(1,2,3);
dosomething ($ar);
```

That piece of code work fine...

What i try to do is to pass the array DIRECTLY to the function
i have try this, non work... HELP !

```
dosomething ([12,32,56]);
dosomething ({12,45,87});
dosomething ("[98,74,52]");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
dosomething( array(12,32,56) );
```

Answer (score 1):

first you have to specify the parameter in the function:

```
function dosomething($array) { var_dump($array); }
```

Then you have to pass the array and define it like you did in your code but directly in the function:

```
dosomething(array(1,2,3));
```