# Is there a cleaner way to send an array from a controller to a function, model or view?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there a more compact way to send an array to a function?

Here's what I'm currently doing:

```php
$data = array(
    'id' => '1'
    );
$result = $this->Tests_model->DoSomething($data);
```

What I'd like to do is just:

```php
$result = $this->Tests_model->DoSomething(array('id' => '1'));
```

or

```php
$result = $this->Tests_model->DoSomething(('id' => '1'));
```

...but I can't seem to format the data inside the ( and ). I still want to pass an array, for better code-reuse. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why the downvote? Can you explain?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I suspect the downvote is because that person thought you should have done more research on array creation syntax. That's probably true, but it's still kind of a mean thing to do to a newb IMO.

Comment: Thanks @DFriend. After having researching this for over an hour, I eventually gave up. That's why I came here. Appreciate the reply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [send array to function in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251236/send-array-to-function-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
$result = $this->Tests_model->DoSomething(array('id' => '1'));
```

is completely valid and can be used.

You need to change the third example to make it work. What you're looking for is

```
$result = $this->Tests_model->DoSomething(['id' => '1']);
```

The syntax `['id' => '1']` is just another way of writing `array('id' => '1')` they produce the exact some thing.

One last way to create an array and add a key/value pair to it is like this.

```
$data['id'] = '1';  //assigns a value of '1' to the key 'id' in an array named $data.
```

The above is just alternate syntax for writing.

```
$data = array('id' => '1');
```

None of these variations on syntax is better or worse other than in terms of "readability" which is often a matter of opinion.

Everything you could want to know about arrays in the [PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).